# SSAS tabular model - how to keep only active model inside RAM

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I expect to have 10-25 TBs of data in my MPP DW in nearest few years. The size of one dataset could be up to 500GB csv. I want to do interactive querying against that data in anaytical tools (Power BI).

I'm looking for a way to achieve interactive querying with reasonable billing.
I know Azure Analytics Services (AAS) Multidimensional Model can be used for that data volumes. But it will give me less performance as tabular model. In other hand, even with 10x compression rate I can't keep everything in RAM simultaneously due to AAS pricing.

*So I'm wondering if there is an possibility to keep all tabular models inside AAS in detached state (disk only) within minimal AAS cluster size (minimal billing), while on request do scale out (increase number of nodes) and attach specific dataset (load from disk to RAM)? Is there any other option to use AAS tabular model and not keeping all 10-25 TBs in RAM simultaneously?*

I assume this option with small amount of concurrent users will have better performance that multidimensional model, while not require keep everything in RAM (less expensive).

Comment: this white paper might be helpful: https://www.sqlbi.com/whitepapers/using-tabular-models-in-a-large-scale-commercial-solution/

Comment: @RADO thanks! will take a look in one-two hours

Comment: I would also look at Azure Synaptic Analytics, that might help in such a large dataset use case with querys and has Power BI/Notebook options

Comment: @Jonee sure, just evaluating different options. Synapse currently show latencies of few minutes in 200 DWU. But maybe something in query is wrong

Comment: I don’t believe you can detach/attach in Azure Analysis Services but you can backup/restore from Blob storage. So I think this is doable. I would guess there would be a 10 minute restore duration after a user requests a dataset be restored. If that’s acceptable this might be a good cost saver.

Comment: Another option might be to spin up many Azure Analysis Servers and leave them paused most of the time ($0 cost). You should time restore vs. unpause when a large model is deployed. My guess is unpause might win.